# Logstash grok filter is slower than Java regex pattern matching

Tags: java, regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I have some syslog messages in RFC-5424 format.

I am using both logstash grok filter and java regex pattern matching to parse the logs. I am comparing both the approaches for the same input.

java regex parsing is reading input from stdin and running in single thread.

Logstash is also reading input from stdin and I have configured worker threads to one and pipeline batch size is equal to number of messages so that all messages are processed in one batch.

**I can see that java regular expression parsing is much faster than grok filter.**

Observations:

Input - 300K messages

Java Regex - 1500 millis

Logstash Grok - more than 1 minute every time.

**Why is Logstash Grok is this much slower than java regex. Grok is also supposed to be using java regexes in backend.**

Answer (score 0):

Without any more details, it is hard to tell why a specific pattern is slower or faster in Grok or Java, but one thing is certain: **the regex engines are different**.

Java uses a special `java.util.regex` module and [Grok uses Oniguruma](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_regular_expressions) regex engine. They may handle the same patterns and strings their own way.

Comment: In grok filter I am using the same regular expression which I am using in my java pattern using format **(?<field_name>the pattern here)**. In java I am parsing the inputs line by line when reading from stdin using buffered reader. In logstash, I am using **stdin{}** for input. 
In both tries, I am discarding the output.
**I think one reason could be that grok is implemented using JRuby and Ruby. Could this be the reason for slowness ?**

Comment: @Rahulkhandelwal: That *can* be the reason, but it does not have to. Regex engines just *differ* in their behavior, syntax they support and performance/stability.

Comment: "*And I'll also mention the truth of performance we've discovered
repeatedly in JRuby: if you don't have fast core classes, you don't
have a fast Ruby implementation. 99% of the performance problems we've investigated over the years could be traced back to core class
implementations, which in most implementations are already written in
a "fast" language like C or Java (Rubinius has a mix of C++ and Ruby
for most core classes, with emphasis on Ruby). So a large number of
poor-performing systems in Ruby can be directly attributed to misuse
or slow implementation of core methods.*"

Comment: Taken from [a Ruby forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/201510#878071). However, I doubt performance will be a problem if your patterns are written in a linear way, if they are efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Wiktor. I don't think that Jruby performance is bad. Grok is able to parse 300K messages in 30 seconds. It's just that it is slower in comparision to Java when I am using exactly same regex for both the processes. So I think this slowness is because of [JRuby itself may be slower than java](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=jruby&lang2=java).

Comment: BTW I also ran into a java port of "Oniguruma", [Joni](https://github.com/jruby/joni). So now we have two approaches for Jruby, either **Jruby -> Ruby -> Oniguruma** OR **Jruby -> Joni**. I am unable to find out that which of them is in picture in case of logstash grok.

Comment: No idea what you now mean. Maybe you should update the question itself. I just pointed out that Grok does not really use Java regex engine, and that a regex performance usually greatly depends on how it is written.

Comment: @Rahulkhandelwal: Please consider upvoting my answer if you found it helpful. Sorry,  I am not sure how to provide a "solution" since your question is not really asking for any. I can't re-write Logstash.